# Unable to locate XML schema namespace, but spring.schemas and spring.handlers are in jar

Tags: java, spring, applicationcontext

I have a java application which is build as jar by gradle. This application uses spring xml context.
If I use it in Eclipse, everything is fine.
When I try to start the application from command line, it downs with the error:

```
D:\docs>java -jar WebserverMinimal.jar
DEBUG: me.test.selfcare.SelfcareMain - app started
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinit
ionParsingException: Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHan
dler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/context]
Offending resource: class path resource [selfcare-integration.xml]

        at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.err
or(FailFastProblemReporter.java:70)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderC
ontext.java:85)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderC
ontext.java:80)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.er
ror(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:316)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.pa
rseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1424)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.pa
rseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1417)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentRe
ader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:174)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentRe
ader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:144)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentRe
ader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:100)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registe
rBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:510)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadB
eanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:392)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBea
nDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBea
nDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReade
r.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReade
r.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReade
r.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReade
r.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:252)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loa
dBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:127)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loa
dBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationCon
text.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtain
FreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refres
h(AbstractApplicationContext.java:452)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<i
nit>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<i
nit>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
        at me.test.selfcare.SelfcareMain.main(SelfcareMain.java:15)
```

I checked the spring.schemas and spring.handlers in jar. There's several files with these names in jar/META-INF. But there's that jar which is in spring-context-4.1.6.jar.

spring.schemas:

```
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd=org/springframework/context/config/spring-context-2.5.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/context/config/spring-context-3.0.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/context/config/spring-context-3.1.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd=org/springframework/context/config/spring-context-3.2.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd=org/springframework/context/config/spring-context-4.0.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd=org/springframework/context/config/spring-context-4.1.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd=org/springframework/context/config/spring-context-4.1.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-2.0.xsd=org/springframework/ejb/config/spring-jee-2.0.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-2.5.xsd=org/springframework/ejb/config/spring-jee-2.5.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/ejb/config/spring-jee-3.0.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/ejb/config/spring-jee-3.1.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.2.xsd=org/springframework/ejb/config/spring-jee-3.2.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-4.0.xsd=org/springframework/ejb/config/spring-jee-4.0.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-4.1.xsd=org/springframework/ejb/config/spring-jee-4.1.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd=org/springframework/ejb/config/spring-jee-4.1.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-2.0.xsd=org/springframework/scripting/config/spring-lang-2.0.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-2.5.xsd=org/springframework/scripting/config/spring-lang-2.5.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/scripting/config/spring-lang-3.0.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/scripting/config/spring-lang-3.1.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-3.2.xsd=org/springframework/scripting/config/spring-lang-3.2.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-4.0.xsd=org/springframework/scripting/config/spring-lang-4.0.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-4.1.xsd=org/springframework/scripting/config/spring-lang-4.1.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd=org/springframework/scripting/config/spring-lang-4.1.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/scheduling/config/spring-task-3.0.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/scheduling/config/spring-task-3.1.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.2.xsd=org/springframework/scheduling/config/spring-task-3.2.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-4.0.xsd=org/springframework/scheduling/config/spring-task-4.0.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-4.1.xsd=org/springframework/scheduling/config/spring-task-4.1.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task.xsd=org/springframework/scheduling/config/spring-task-4.1.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/cache/config/spring-cache-3.1.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache-3.2.xsd=org/springframework/cache/config/spring-cache-3.2.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache-4.0.xsd=org/springframework/cache/config/spring-cache-4.0.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache-4.1.xsd=org/springframework/cache/config/spring-cache-4.1.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache.xsd=org/springframework/cache/config/spring-cache-4.1.xsd
```

spring.handlers:

```
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/context=org.springframework.context.config.ContextNamespaceHandler
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/jee=org.springframework.ejb.config.JeeNamespaceHandler
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/lang=org.springframework.scripting.config.LangNamespaceHandler
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/task=org.springframework.scheduling.config.TaskNamespaceHandler
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/cache=org.springframework.cache.config.CacheNamespaceHandler
```

I can't figure out, why it doesn't see the xsd file which is located in jar like is written in mapping?

There's class where I try to initialize spring application context:

```
package me.test.selfcare;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class SelfcareMain {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SelfcareMain.class);

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        log.debug("app started");
        String contextName="classpath:selfcare-integration.xml";
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(contextName);
        log.debug("spring context is initialized");
    }

}
```

application context xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="me.test.selfcare.domain" />

    <object-to-json-transformer 
        input-channel="input"
        output-channel="json" />

    <channel id="input" />

    <channel id="json">
        <queue capacity="10" />
    </channel>

</beans:beans>
```

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'

compileJava.options.encoding = 'UTF-8'

version = '1.0'

sourceCompatibility = 1.7
targetCompatibility = 1.7

task createJar(type: Jar) {
    archiveName = "WebserverMinimal.jar"
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'Gradle Jar File Example',  
            'Implementation-Version': version,
            'Main-Class': 'me.test.selfcare.SelfcareMain'
    }
    baseName = project.name
    from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
    with jar
}

task copyJarToBin {
    doLast {
        copy {
            from 'build/libs/WebserverMinimal.jar'
            into "d:/docs/svn_bolid_bin/bin/Debug/Modules"
        }
        copy {
            from 'build/libs/WebserverMinimal.jar'
            into "d:/docs/svn_bolid_bin/bin/Release/Modules"
        }
    }
}
copyJarToBin.mustRunAfter createJar

task buildWebserver (dependsOn: [clean, createJar, copyJarToBin])

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:7.0.16'
    compile 'org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-logging-log4j:7.0.16'
    compile 'org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:1.7.9'
    compile 'log4j:log4j:1.2.17'
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:1.7.9'
    compile 'com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1.1'

    compile 'org.springframework:spring-core:4.1.6.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-beans:4.1.6.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-context:4.1.6.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-core:4.1.6.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-jms:4.1.6.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-lgpl:1.9.9'
    compile 'javax.jms:javax.jms-api:2.0.1'
    compile 'org.apache.activemq:activemq-core:5.7.0'
}

uploadArchives {
    repositories {
       flatDir {
           dirs 'repos'
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For initializing spring context you should add all 5 core spring jars to dependencies.

```
compile 'org.springframework:spring-aop:4.1.7.RELEASE'
compile 'org.springframework:spring-beans:4.1.7.RELEASE'
compile 'org.springframework:spring-context:4.1.7.RELEASE'
compile 'org.springframework:spring-core:4.1.7.RELEASE'
compile 'org.springframework:spring-expression:4.1.7.RELEASE'
```